# Map an array key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

The key value of my array is another array. I want to filter only the array value.

This is my array:

```js
const array = [{
    work: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      number: 8
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Tuesday',
      number: 5
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Saturday',
      number: 4
    }]
  },
]
```

My desired array is:

```
const desiredArray = [{
  day: 'Monday',
  number: 8
}, {
  day: 'Tuesday',
  number: 5
}, {
  day: 'Saturday',
  number: 4
}];
```

I have tried

```
const desiredArray  = Object.values(array)
const desiredArray  = Object.keys(array).map(item => array[item])
```

neither of which worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get the desired output:

```js
const input = [{
  work: [{ day: 'Monday', number: 8 }]
}, {
  work: [{ day: 'Tuesday', number: 5 }]
}, {
  work: [{ day: 'Saturday', number: 4 }]
}];

const output = input.flatMap(({ work }) => work);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ... or simply `input.flatMap(({ work }) => work)`

Comment: @blex Thanks for the valuable input. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to return a new array from the given array.

```js
const array = [{
    work: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      number: 8
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Tuesday',
      number: 5
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Saturday',
      number: 4
    }]
  },
]

const desired = array.map(item => item.work[0]);

console.log(desired);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `flat`.

`array.map(Object.values).flat(2)`

```js
const array = [{
    work: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      number: 8
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Tuesday',
      number: 5
    }]
  },
  {
    work: [{
      day: 'Saturday',
      number: 4
    }]
  },
]

console.log(array.map(Object.values).flat(2))
```